# SQL Server tables in wrong database

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and have a strange problem, I have created a database named `zed` and a user `zed` which is mapped to the `zed` database but when I try to create the tables from a script :

```
sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-TEDE7TP\SQLEXPRESS -U zed -P zedfinancials -i ../tables/static_tables.sql
```

The tables are created in the `master` database.

Comment: You didn't specify the database in the command line or the script so the default database for that user is used

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `-d` flag to set the database :

```
sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-TEDE7TP\SQLEXPRESS -U zed -P zedfinancials -d zed -i ../tables/static_tables.sql
```

Read more about `sqlcmd` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Try these 2 lines in the beginning of your script file (static_tables.sql):

```
USE [Zed]
GO
```

This will force the script to use the database specified.